# Tensorflow compute_output_shape() Not Working For Custom Layer

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a custom layer (called GraphGather) in Keras, yet the output tensor prints as :

> Tensor("graph_gather/Tanh:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)

For some reason the shape is being returned as (?,?), which is causing the next dense layer to raise the following error:

> ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

The GraphGather layer code is as follows:

```py
class GraphGather(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, batch_size, num_mols_in_batch, activation_fn=None, **kwargs):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.num_mols_in_batch = num_mols_in_batch
    self.activation_fn = activation_fn
    super(GraphGather, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    super(GraphGather, self).build(input_shape)

 def call(self, x, **kwargs):
    # some operations (most of def call omitted)
    out_tensor = result_of_operations() # this line is pseudo code
    if self.activation_fn is not None:
      out_tensor = self.activation_fn(out_tensor)
    out_tensor = out_tensor
    return out_tensor

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (self.num_mols_in_batch, 2 * input_shape[0][-1])}
```

`I have also tried hardcoding compute_output_shape to be:`
python
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (64, 150)
```
Yet the output tensor when printed is still

> Tensor("graph_gather/Tanh:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)

which causes the ValueError written above.

---

#### System information

- Have written custom code
- **OS Platform and Distribution*:  Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.5.0
- **Python version**: 3.5.5

Comment: maybe it expects same number of examples in next layer, and problem is in batch size component in shape?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. My workaround was to add the following lines to the call method:

```
input_shape = tf.shape(x)
```

and then:

```
return tf.reshape(out_tensor, self.compute_output_shape(input_shape))
```

I haven't run into any problems with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If Johnny's answer doesn't work, I found another way to get around this is to follow advice here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38296#issuecomment-623698709

which is to call the `set_shape` method on the output of your layer.

E.g.

```
l=GraphGather(...)
y=l(x)
y.set_shape( l.compute_output_shape(x.shape) )
```

This only works if you are using the functional API.